# Como somar dois arrays de inteiros com aritmética de ponteiro?

Tags: c, ponteiro

Estou fazendo um exercício em que passo por parâmetro dois arrays de inteiros já definidos pelo usuário. Preciso agora, em um terceiro array, armazenar a soma dos dois arrays recebidos, nas mesmas posições, utilizando aritmética de ponteiro.

Ex:

```
vet 1 [1,2,3]
vet 2 [1,2,3]
```

Aqui no terceiro vetor tenho que receber a soma utilizando aritmética de ponteiro.

```
vet 3 [2,4,6]
```

Minha tentativa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100
int soma_ponteiro(int *vet1,int *vet2,int num);
int main(){

    int vet1[MAX],vet2[MAX];
    int num,i;

    printf("Digite qtd de numeros:\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        printf("\nDigite numero %d vetor 1\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&vet1[i]);
        printf("\nDigite numero %d vetor 2\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&vet2[i]);
    }

    soma_ponteiro(vet1,vet2,num);
    printf("\n%d",soma_ponteiro(vet1,vet2,num));

    return 0;
}
int soma_ponteiro(int *vet1,int *vet2,int num){
    int vet3[MAX];
    int *last_pos=vet1+num;
    int *ptr = vet1;
    int *ptr2= vet2;
    int *ptr3= vet3;

    while(ptr<last_pos){
        *ptr3 = *vet1+*vet2;
    ptr++;
    }
    return ptr3;
}
```

Comment: Seja mais específico em sua pergunta. O que você tentou fazer? O que não deu certo?

Comment: Dei um downvote pois sua pergunta não demonstra esforço nenhum. Mostre seu código, diga o que tentou, o que não soube fazer, etc.

Comment: Ok, já passei os vetores 1 e 2 preenchidos pelo usuario, ele escolhe qual o tamanho dos vetores 1 e 2 e os preenche. Minha dúvida principal é como devo receber a soma desses vetores usando aritmética de ponteiros, não posso percorre-los com laço e soma-los, tem q ser com aritmetica de ponteiro. Segue minha função  int soma_ponteiro(int *vet1,int *vet2,int num){
    int vet3[MAX];
    int *last_pos=vet1+num;
    int *ptr = vet1;
    int *ptr2= vet2;
    int *ptr3= vet3;

    while(ptr<last_pos){
        *ptr3 = *vet1+*vet2;
    ptr++;
    }
    return ptr3;
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veja se é isto o que deseja:

```
int vet1[3]={1, 2, 3}, vet2[3]={1, 2, 3}, vet3[3], *p1, *p2, *p3, i;
p1 = vet1;
p2 = vet2;
p3 = vet3;
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    *p3 = *p1 + *p2;
    p1++;
    p2++;
    p3++;
}
for (i=0; i<3;i++)
    printf("\tvet3[%d] = %d", i, vet3[i]);
```

Comment: Cara show de bola, precisa abstrair mesmo, com o laço assim ficou perfeito.

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir fazer operações entre dois vectores numa função tem que cumprir estas "regras":

1. Passar os vectores por parâmetro
2. Passar a dimensão dos vectores por parâmetro

Depois disso é só percorrer o vector num ciclo, pode usar um contador `i`, e usar o array sem ponteiros, desta forma: `vector[i] = 1 + 2;` ou então `*(vector + i) = 1 + 2`