# Como inicializar uma matriz usando ponteiros?

Tags: c, ponteiro, matriz

Preciso inicializar uma matriz com 0 usando ponteiro para endereçar seus elementos

Comment: O que você tentou? Coloque seu código que não está funcionando.

Comment: -1. Fabao, essa pergunta é clássica de curso, e você não demonstrou esforço nem descreveu bem o que queria. Por favor, procure se esforçar um pouco mais _pelo menos_ ao fazer uma pergunta como essa

Answer (score 5):

Veja se é isto que você deseja:

```
int main()
{
    int matriz[5][5], i, *ponteiro;
    ponteiro = matriz[0];
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        *ponteiro = 0;
        ponteiro++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

É praticamente a mesma coisa que foi respondida na sua pergunta [soma de vetor com ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5545/como-somar-dois-arrays-de-inteiros-com-aritmetica-de-ponteiro).

Comment: Pessoal, é exercício, deixem o OP se esforçar um pouco em vez de entregar tudo na mão...

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <string.h>

/* ... */

int matrix[3][4];
memset(matrix, 0, 3 * 4 * sizeof(int));
```

A função `memset` recebe um ponteiro, um valor e uma quantidade. Ela vai preencher aquela quantidade de bytes a partir do ponteiro com aquele valor.

Como o tamanho é em bytes, a quantidade deve ser multiplicada pelo tamanho do tipo da matriz.

Edit: Conforme sugerido no comentário dessa resposta, é possível fazer o seguinte também:

```
memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(matrix));
```

Isso é possível porque o compilador sabe o tamanho completo da matriz, já que suas dimensões estão definidas na variável. Mas se você em vez disso tivesse um ponteiro para a matriz, isso não seria possível:

```
int *ptr = &matrix[0][0];
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr));         /* ERRADO:  vai zerar apenas o primeiro elemento */
memset(ptr, 0, 3 * 4 * sizeof(int)); /* CORRETO: vai zerar toda a matriz */
```

Comment: Ou ainda `memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(matrix));`. (Eu acho que a questão era de um exercício e ele queria um loop, mas `memset` é de fato a forma correta de fazer isso. +1)

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Certamente, só não sugeri isso para que a resposta ficasse bem clara para ele. E provavelmente é um exercício sim. Mas o enunciado não especificava que tinha de usar loop, ou que não podia usar funções da biblioteca padrão :)

Comment: Pessoal, é exercício, deixem o OP se esforçar um pouco em vez de entregar tudo na mão...

Answer (score 4):

Quatro formas de zerar uma matriz me veem à cabeça, dentre elas a mais fácil seria essa:

```
int matriz[5][5] = {0};
```

A normal, nível básico, seria essa:

```
int matriz[5][5], i, j;
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        matriz[i][j]=0;
    }
}
```

Um intermediário, creio que seja esse que você quer, seria trabalhar com ponteiros. Como a alocação é sequencial, os próximos valores, ou anteriores, sempre estarão na casa ao lado, indo do começo ao fim de `matriz`. Só vejo uso para algo do tipo em uma função auxiliar, pois dessa forma é completamente uma perca de tempo, não há necessidade.

```
int matriz[5][5], i, j, *ptr=matriz;
for (i=0; i<25; i++, ptr++)
{
    *ptr=0;
}
```

E tem o método avançado, com `memset()`, aqui você mexe diretamente com a memória, o primeiro argumento é o vetor, o segundo é o valor a ser *setado* e o terceiro a quantidade de valores do vetor a ser *setado* em bytes. Você precisa, primeiramente, saber com qual tipo de dado está trabalhando, seu tamanho em bytes, utiliza-se função `sizeof()` que recebe o dado e retorna a quantidade de bytes alocados para esse tal dado. Então, para zerar `matriz` você poderia fazer apenas isso:

```
memset(matriz, 0, sizeof(matriz));
```

Comment: Apenas complementando: Embora soe contra-intuitivo, `int matriz[5][5] = {1};` **não** produzirá uma matriz de uns. O que ocorre é que se você não especificar todos os elementos na lista de inicialização, eles serão zero. No entanto você deve especificar ao menos um elemento (`{}` não é válido). Então `{1}` produz o primeiro elemento `1` e ou outros `0`.

Comment: Sim, você está correto, Guilherme. E acabou me lembrando um outro recurso para um caso como esse descrito por você: `int matriz[5][5] = { [0 ... 4][0 ... 4] = 1 };`. São os chamados [inicializadores designados](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits)